# Game of Snap Probability

Tags: probability, card-games

If you don't know how snap works - two players get 26 cards each from a standard 52 card deck. They then place their cards in a shared pile of cards where the cards are visible to both of them. If two cards of the same rank are placed right after each other, they call the snap. My question is what the probability is that this does not occur until both players have placed down 3 cards each. If possible, could you use the hypergeomtric distrubition, seeing as the cards are not replaced and kept in a pile in the middle.

Comment: Why do you assume there must be a match within four cards?  There are $13$ ranks, so it could be six turns without a match.

Comment: I misphrased that, I meant what is the probability that the first three rounds of each do not have a match

Comment: But there is no matching between rounds, so if we draw $A,2$ on the first and $3,A$ on the second there is no match yet?

Comment: yeah :D
Also important to note. If the first person plays a 2, and a 3 is put on top by the second player. If the first player places another 2 it wouldn't count as a snap.

Comment: Then if the first draw is $A,2$ and the second draw is $2,3$ we have a match because the two $2$s are showing together after the first player plays and before the second?  We need to get the rules clear.

Comment: Each player places down one at a time and a pile will build up of cards. If the first person plays a two, the card right after that also has to be a two in order for there to be a match. If there is two cards of the same rank in a row it means there is a match.

Comment: Please edit the question to carefully specify the rules.  Can there be a match between the two cards the players play in the same round, or just in the pile of one player?

Comment: They are sharing the pile

Comment: It sounds like you want the second card played to be of different rank than the first, the third card of different rank than the second, the fourth of different rank than the third, and the fifth of different rank than the fourth. Do you want the sixth card to be of different rank than the fifth (i.e., there's no snap until *after* the third round), or can it be of the same rank?

Comment: Yeah I want it all the way up to 6th being different from 7th. So how would i figure out the probability of that occruing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather from the comments that the two-player structure of the game is in fact irrelevant and you're simply interested in the probability of no two consecutive cards of seven cards drawn from a shuffled standard deck having the same rank.

The probability for a rank match in each particular pair of consecutive cards is

$$
\frac{13\cdot\binom42}{\binom{52}2}=\frac1{17}\;.
$$

As a first crude approximation, the probability of a match occurring is roughly the expected number of matches, $\frac6{17}$, which would make the probability for no match to occur

$$
1-\frac6{17}=\frac{11}{17}\approx0.647\;.
$$

As a second, much better approximation, we can treat the match events as roughly independent and calculate the probability of none of them occurring as

$$
\left(1-\frac1{17}\right)^6=\left(\frac{16}{17}\right)^6=\frac{16777216}{24137569}\approx0.6951\;.
$$

The exact probability can be calculated using a Markov chain or inclusion–exclusion, but with both approaches it would require quite a bit of casework.

---

P.S.: Here's the casework to do it by inclusion–exclusion.

We have $6$ conditions, namely that none of the $6$ possible rank matches occur.

The probability for one particular condition to be violated is $\frac1{17}$, and there are $6$ of them, for a contribution of $-\frac6{17}$.

Two particular conditions can be violated in two different ways. There are $5$ cases where the two matches are adjacent, and in this case the probability for both matches to occur is

$$
\frac{13\cdot\binom43}{\binom{52}3}=\frac1{425}\;,
$$

so this yields a contribution $\frac5{425}=\frac1{85}$. And there are $\binom62-5=10$ cases where the two matches aren't adjacent, and in this case the probability for both matches to occur is

$$
\frac{\frac13\binom{13}2\binom42^2+13}{\binom{52}4}=\frac{73}{20825}\;,
$$

so this yields a contribution $\frac{10\cdot73}{20825}=\frac{146}{4165}$.

Since it's quite unlikely for $3$ matches to occur, we should already get quite a good approximation if we were to stop at this point:

$$
1-\frac6{17}+\frac1{85}+\frac{146}{4165}=\frac{34}{49}\approx0.6938776\;,
$$

as expected quite close to the already quite good second approximation above.

With diminishing returns in precision, let's do the calculation for three matches. There are $4$ cases in which these are all adjacent, and the probability for three adjacent matches is

$$
\frac{13}{\binom{52}4}=\frac1{20825}\;,
$$

for a contribution of $-\frac4{20825}$. There are $4$ cases in which none of the three matches are adjacent, and the probability for such a case to occur is

$$
\frac{\frac1{15}\binom{13}3\binom42^3+\frac15\cdot13\cdot12\cdot\binom42}{\binom{52}6}=\frac{207}{978775}\;,
$$

for a contribution of $-\frac{4\cdot207}{978775}=-\frac{828}{978775}$. In the remaining $\binom63-4-4=12$ cases, two matches are adjacent and the third isn't adjacent to either of them. The probability for such a case to occur is

$$
\frac{\frac1{10}13\cdot\binom43\cdot12\cdot\binom42}{\binom{52}5}=\frac3{20825}\;,
$$

for a contribution of $-\frac{12\cdot3}{20825}=-\frac{36}{20825}$.

So our next level of approximation, already quite precise, is

$$
\frac{34}{49}-\frac4{20825}-\frac{828}{978775}-\frac{36}{20825}=\frac{676442}{978775}\approx0.6911108\;.
$$

Since not too many cases remain, we might as well do the rest, too.

Four matches can't all be adjacent. We can have three of them adjacent and one separate. There are $6$ such cases, and the probability for each is

$$
\frac{\frac1{15}\cdot13\cdot12\cdot\binom42}{\binom{52}6}=\frac3{978775}\;,
$$

for a contribution of $\frac{6\cdot3}{978775}=\frac{18}{978775}$.

Or we can have two pairs of them adjacent. There are $3$ such cases, and the probability for each is

$$
\frac{\frac1{10}\binom{13}2\binom43^2}{\binom{52}6}=\frac6{978775}\;,
$$

for another contribution of $\frac{3\cdot6}{978775}=\frac{18}{978775}$.

Or we can have two of them adjacent and the other two separate. There are $3$ such cases, and the probability for one of them to occur is

$$
\frac{\frac1{35}\cdot\frac13\cdot13\binom{12}2\binom43\binom42^2+\frac1{35}\cdot13\cdot12\binom43}{\binom{52}7}=\frac{201}{22511825}\;,
$$

for a contribution of $\frac{3\cdot201}{22511825}=\frac{603}{22511825}$.

So our next approximation is

$$
\frac{676442}{978775}+\frac{18}{978775}+\frac{18}{978775}+\frac{603}{22511825}=\frac{15559597}{22511825}\approx0.6911744\;.
$$

Finally, with $5$ matches, no $4$ of them can be adjacent. That only leaves $2$ cases in which $3$ and $2$ of them are adjacent, and the probability for such a case to occur is

$$
\frac{\frac1{35}\cdot13\cdot12\binom43}{\binom{52}7}=\frac3{22511825}\;,
$$

for a contribution of $-\frac{2\cdot3}{22511825}=-\frac6{22511825}$. Since $6$ matches are impossible, that gives us our final exact result:

$$
\frac{15559597}{22511825}-\frac6{22511825}=\frac{15559591}{22511825}\approx0.6911741\;.
$$

[Here's code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/e5f8cdb7a16822add919ae9c5e1fea26) that checks these results (both the final tally and the individual contributions).

Comment: Thank you :D
However, I can't tell if you've included replacement or not. After the first card gets played, there will be 51 cards in total, then 50, and so on.

Comment: @JuliusSnijders: Where do you think this could have made a difference?

Comment: When using 52 chose 2 at the beginning. The line after that should be 51 chose 2, instead of maintaining 17 denominator

Comment: @JuliusSnijders: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Which line after that? The one that starts with "As a first crude approximation"? I'm just adding up the expected number of matches there. Each match has a probability of $\frac1{17}$ to occur; I don't see how $\binom{51}2$ comes in there. Are you saying that later matches have a different probability to occur than the first match?

Comment: Yes, because there is no replacement. The cards stay in the pile in the middle. Thus, there will be less total cards from the pile, making 51 cards instead of 52.

Comment: @JuliusSnijders: That's wrong. Each match has exactly the same marginal probability of occurring. It doesn't matter in which order you consider them. It doesn't matter that cards have been taken out of the deck before the later matches (unless you condition on those cards, which I'm not doing here). The fact that $5$ cards have been taken out of the deck before the $6$th match attempt is as irrelevant as it would be if you moved $5$ cards from the top of the deck to the bottom after shuffling it; that doesn't affect the probability of a match.

Comment: Thank you so much homie :D